# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'module' while importing my own module VsCode MacOs Python 3.10

Tags: python-3.x, macos, visual-studio-code, import, module

Structure:

```
|--folder/
    |--a.py
|--main.py
```

When loading module 'main' into module 'a'

```
#a.py
import main
```

the following error occurs - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'main'.

PyCharm copes with this task, but VSCode does not. What's the matter?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your directory structure, I presume that a.py and main.py are in different directories. If that is the case, then the answers to [this question][1] should be useful. To elaborate a bit further, you can use the sys module to specify the path to the other module (main.py) i.e. if main.py is in a different directory from a.py.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path_to_main_module_directory/')

import main
print("This import is for the main module")
```

I hope this helps!
[1]: [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Comment: thanks. great answer other than that it`s hardcoded. What to do if I transfer the project to another server.

Comment: I used an absolute path in my example, you should use a relative path, so if you move your project to a different server, it will/should be mapped to the directory specified. Lookup absolute and relative paths...just in case :)